# What does address.send(amount) do, step by step?

Tags: solidity

When this is in the Solidity Contract ...

```
address.send(amount)
```

... what happens specifically on my node and blockchain? Step by step.

And, in this case is the *throw state* or the *SuccessEvent()* executed immediately?

```
if (!celler.send(dealAmount)){
    throw;
} else{
    SuccessEvent();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question a little to help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're questioning timing and flow control and maybe thinking about mining delays and so on.

There's a delay to mine a transaction, but you don't need to consider that delay *inside a transaction* because transactions always execute or fail completely.

Your `address.send()` returns a true/false success/failure result to your contract. You can safely think about that as happening immediately. It will log an event if the `send()` succeeded, or nothing will happen if the `send()` failed, because (`throw`).

There's no time delay between the `send()` and the event because each new block presents an internally consistent picture of the accepted transactions and the results.

Step-by-step:

1. Someone sends a transaction to a function
2. Miners run the contract and discover if it succeeds or fails. If it succeeds, what changed? There was a value transfer and an event.
3. If the transaction succeeded, it gets included in a block and the state changes are part of the blockchain.
4. If it failed (`throw`), miners ignore the transaction and there will be no state changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As for `SuccessEvent()`, it’s invoked on your node when you receive a block containing the successful transaction.

Comment: Good point. That's when the node knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

All EVM code is executed sequentially, like any other programming language where there is no implicit or explicit asynchronous clls.

Both `throw` and `Event` creation are executed immediately.

If the contract called in a transaction throws, then the whole transaction is rolled back with out of gas (invalid jump) error. Miners still get their gas.

If a contract is called from another contract and the function throws then the transaction is not rolled back, but this is handled as a boolean return value.